# Can two different criteria be used with DLOOKUP if they have two different data types?

Tags: ms-access

I have a form that tracks the missed questions on a test. It has a linked child form that tracks the individual questions that the person taking the test missed.
[image]
I want to, when I enter a missed question number, [QuestionNumber] to have the form prefill in the required retraining [RetrainAssigned] from a table of question numbers (tblTestQuestionsTitles)

On the After Update property of Question Number field of the child form I have the following code:

```
Dim RLAAssignedX As String
RLAAssignedX = DLookup("[AssocRLA]", "tblTestQuestionsTitles", ("[QuestionNumber] = " & Me.QuestionNumber And "[AssessmentTitle] = " & Me.Parent!Title))
Me.RLAAssigned = RLAAssignedX
```

I am getting error 13 - Type Mismatch in data expression, and the debug is highlighting the entire line. QuestionNumber and AssessmentTitle are number fields in all tables. Retraining Assigned is a Text Field - but that is the output of the dlookup not a criteria. All I can think of is that the output and the criteria also have to match but that's not matching what I have tried to lookup here and on google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're referencing values held by the active form, you should be able to reference the values of such fields directly within the selection criteria of the `DLookup` expression, without the need for concatenation nor consideration for the data type of the field being filtered, e.g.:

```
DLookup("[AssocRLA]", "tblTestQuestionsTitles", "[QuestionNumber] = [Forms]![YourParentFormName]![YourSubFormName].Form![QuestionNumber] AND [AssessmentTitle] = [Forms]![YourParentFormName]![Title]")
```

This approach also avoids the potential for SQL injection.

Comment: Yes, except subform must be referenced through parent form and subform container control.

Comment: Thanks both of you! This worked very well. I didnt consider referencing the values directly. I'm so used to the parent/child thing because I use a lot of sub-forms.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, WHERE argument can include multiple criteria of different data types but you say yours are both number type.

Concatenation is not correct. RLAAssignedX is declared a String variable. If DLookup does not find a match, it will return Null. String variable cannot hold Null and code will run-time error. If Null is a possibility, need to handle that. Actually, don't really need variable.

```
Me.RLAAssigned = DLookup("[AssocRLA]", "tblTestQuestionsTitles", _
"[QuestionNumber] = " & Me.QuestionNumber & " And [AssessmentTitle] = " & Me.Parent!Title)
```